# Trying to binding the combobox with mysql and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html-table

I have a problem with combobox filling with data.

I have a table **user** with columns:

- usrIndex
- usrNickname
- usrFullname
- usrEmail

We are binding the data include joins with other table (like hrh...) and we are caluculating user heart rate and their calories like that, by using following code:

```
$totalPoints = 0;
$totalDuration = 0;
$totalCalories = 0;
$noOfParticipants = 0;
$includedUsers = 0;
$participants = "";
```

Main  Program

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT usrIndex,usrNickname";
$query .= " FROM hrheader hrh";
$query .= " INNER JOIN `user` usr ON hrh.hrhUsrIndex=usr.usrIndex";
$query .= " WHERE usrSIndex=$sIndex";
$query .= " AND hrhStart>'" . $start . "' AND hrhStart<'" . date("Y-m-d", strtotime($end . " +1 days")) . "'";
$query .= " ORDER BY usrNickname";

$gresult = mysql_query($query);
if ($gresult) 
{
    $noOfParticipants = mysql_num_rows($gresult);
    $participants = "<table style='text-align:center;font-size:18px;width:980px;margin-   top:16px;color:#231f20;'>";
    $participants .= "<tr>";
    $participants .= "<th>Nickname</th><th>Time (Hours &amp; Mins)</th><th>Average Effort</th><th>Calories</th><th><img src='../images/mepslogo.png' /></th>";
    $participants .= "</tr>";
```

The below code and diagram helps for clearly understanding the question:

```
while ($grow = mysql_fetch_array($gresult)) 
{
    $query = "SELECT ROUND(AVG(hr/hrhMaxHR)*100) AS AverageEffort,ROUND(AVG(hr)) AS AverageHeartRate,ROUND(MAX(hr)) AS MaxHeartRate,";
    $query .= " COUNT(DISTINCT hrhIndex) AS NumberOfMoves";
    $query .= " FROM `hrheader` hrh INNER JOIN hr ON hrh.hrhIndex=hr.hrHrhIndex";
    $query .= " WHERE hrhUsrIndex=" . $grow['usrIndex'] . " AND hr>0";
    $query .= " AND hrReceivedTime>'" . $start . "' AND hrReceivedTime<'" . date("Y-m-d", strtotime($end . " +1 days")) . "'";

    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $pAverageEffort = 0;
    $pAverageHeartRate = 0;
    $pMaxHeartRate = 0;
    $pNumberOfMoves = 0;

    if ($result)
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        if ($row) 
        {
            $pAverageEffort = $row['AverageEffort'] . "%";
            $pAverageHeartRate = $row['AverageHeartRate'];
            $pMaxHeartRate = $row['MaxHeartRate'];
            $pNumberOfMoves = $row['NumberOfMoves'];
        }
    }

    $query = "SELECT hr,hrReceivedTime,hrhMaxHR,hrhWeight,FLOOR(DATEDIFF(hrReceivedTime,usrDOB)/365) AS Age,usrGender";
    $query .= " FROM hrheader hrh INNER JOIN hr ON hrh.hrhIndex=hr.hrHrhIndex";
    $query .= " INNER JOIN `user` usr ON hrh.hrhUsrIndex=usr.usrIndex";
    $query .= " WHERE hrhUsrIndex=" . $grow['usrIndex'] . " AND hr>0";
    $query .= " AND hrReceivedTime>'" . $start . "' AND hrReceivedTime<'" . date("Y-m-d", strtotime($end . " +1 days")) . "'";
    $query .= " ORDER BY hrReceivedTime";
    //echo $query;
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $lastReceived = false;

    if ($result) 
    {
        $t = 0;
        $pDuration = 0;

        $zone1 = 0;
        $zone2 = 0;
        $zone3 = 0;
        $zone4 = 0;
        $zone5 = 0;
        $count = 0;
        $pCalories = 0;

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            if ($lastReceived)
            {
                $t = TimeDifference($lastReceived, $row['hrReceivedTime']);
                if ($t < 5)
                {
                    if ($row['hr'] > 0) 
                    {
                        if ($row['hr'] > $row['hrhMaxHR'] * 0.9) 
                        {
                            $zone5 += $t;
                        }
                        elseif ($row['hr'] > $row['hrhMaxHR'] * 0.8)
                        {
                            $zone4 += $t;
                        }
                        elseif ($row['hr'] > $row['hrhMaxHR'] * 0.7)
                        {
                            $zone3 += $t;
                        }
                        elseif ($row['hr'] > $row['hrhMaxHR'] * 0.6)
                        {
                            $zone2 += $t;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $zone1 += $t;
                        }
                        $count++;
                        $pDuration += $t;
                        $pCalories += calculateCalPerMin($row['hr'], $row['hrhWeight'], $row['Age'], $row['usrGender']) * $t;
                    }
                }
            }
            $lastReceived = $row['hrReceivedTime'];
        }
        $zone1 = floor($zone1);
        $zone2 = floor($zone2);
        $zone3 = floor($zone3);
        $zone4 = floor($zone4);
        $zone5 = floor($zone5);

        $pPoints = 0;
        $pPoints+=calculatePoints(1, $zone1);
        $pPoints+=calculatePoints(2, $zone2);
        $pPoints+=calculatePoints(3, $zone3);
        $pPoints+=calculatePoints(4, $zone4);
        $pPoints+=calculatePoints(5, $zone5);

        $totalCalories+=$pCalories;
        $totalPoints+=$pPoints;
        $totalDuration+=$pDuration;

        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) 
        {
            mysql_data_seek($result, 0);
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            $include = 1;
            if (!empty($targetGroup)) 
            {
                if ($targetGroup != $row['usrGender'])
                {
                    $include = 0;
                }
            }
            if (!empty($targetNoOfSessions)) 
            {
                if ($targetNoOfSessions < $pNumberOfMoves) 
                {
                    $include = 0;
                }
            }
            if (!empty($targetDuration))
            {
                $x = explode(":", $targetDuration);
                $targetDuration = ($x[0] * 60) + $x[1];
                if ($targetDuration < $pDuration)
                {
                    $include = 0;
                }
            }
            if (!empty($targetAveEffort))
            {
                if ($targetAveEffort > floor($pAverageEffort))
                {
                    $include = 0;
                }
            }
            if (!empty($targetTimeInZones))
            {
                $targetTimeInZones = intval($targetTimeInZones);
                if (!empty($targetTimeInZones))
                {
                    switch ($targetTimeInZones)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            if (empty($zone1))
                                $include = 0;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            if (empty($zone2))
                                $include = 0;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            if (empty($zone3))
                                $include = 0;
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            if (empty($zone4))
                                $include = 0;
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            if (empty($zone5))
                                $include = 0;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!empty($targetCalories))
            {
                if ($targetCalories >= $pCalories)
                {
                    $include = 0;
                }
            }
            if (!empty($targetPoints))
            {
                $debug .= "$targetPoints - $pPoints --";
                if ($targetPoints >= $pPoints)
                {
                    $include = 0;
                }
            }

            if ($include == 1)
            {
                $includedUsers+=1;
            }
        }
        if ($include == 1)
        {
            $participants .= "<tr><td>" . $grow['usrNickname'] . "</td><td>" . FormatTime($pDuration) . "</td><td>$pAverageEffort</td><td>" . floor($pCalories) . "</td><td>$pPoints</td></tr>";
        }
    }
}
$participants .= "</table>";
```

and this is html code for Main program (here we are defining the html table):

```
<div class="txt" style="margin-right:10px;margin-top:16px;font-size:18px;width:462px;float:right">
    <div class="txtl"></div>
    <div class="txtr"></div>
    <span>% of group that achieved target</span>
    <span id="spanPercentAchieved" style="color:black;float:right">-%</span>
</div>
<div class="txt" style="margin-left:10px;margin-top:16px;font-size:18px;width:462px">
    <div class="txtl"></div>
    <div class="txtr"></div>
    <span>Number of users achieved target</span>
    <span id="spanNumberAchieved" style="color:black;float:right">-</span>
</div>
<span id="spanParticipants">
    <table style='text-align:center;font-size:18px;width:980px;margin-top:16px;color:#231f20;'>
        <tr>
            <th>Nickname</th>
            <th>No of Sessions</th>
            <th>Duration</th>
            <th>Average Effort</th>
            <th><img src='../images/mepslogo.png' /></th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</span>
```

I have indicated the query and binding the data to html table in   "Main Program"

Its working fine with this code...... But my problem is

I want to set the combobox inside html table at nickname header in that combobox the options are like (Nickname , Full Name, Email)  when the user select these options (full name, email) they will able to see the users email and full name those whose nickname is currently displayed ..

I want like this:

[image]

If the user select the full name, full name will be displayed instead of Nickname and when the user select the email id the email id will be displayed instead of nickname of the users.

This combox selection will be set in table column header.

Would anyone please help on this?

Can anyone help on this one...this topic.

Comment: Much better :-) And you've got an answer!

Comment: @jam any way this is not working ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You looking for somthing like this?
http://test.puggan.se/test/column_test.php

This is a plain javascript soulotion, tested in firefox, 
There probely an easier solution whit JQuery.
if you tag you question whit [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) or [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), 
you probely get a few more answer of people that know thous langueges

code in exemple linked above:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>select column test</title>
        <script>
            function select_column(column_name)
            {
                document.getElementById('column_style').textContent = '.col_hideable div.col_' + column_name + ' {display: block;}';
            }
        </script>
        <style id='column_style'>
            .col_hideable div.col_nick_name {display: block;}
        </style>
        <style>
            TH, TD {border: solid gray 1px;}
            .col_hideable div {display: none;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id='the_table'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <select id='column_selector' onchange='select_column(this.value)'>
                            <option value='nick_name'>Nickname</option>
                            <option value='full_name'>Full name</option>
                            <option value='email'>Email</option>
                        </select>
                    </th>
                    <th>junk</th>
                    <th>junk</th>
                    <th>junk</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class='col_hideable'>
                        <div class='col_nick_name col_hideable'>nickname 1</div>
                        <div class='col_full_name'>fullname 1</div>
                        <div class='col_email'>email 1</div>
                    </td>
                    <td> junk 1-2 </td>
                    <td> junk 1-3 </td>
                    <td> junk 1-4 </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class='col_hideable'>
                        <div class='col_nick_name'>nickname 2</div>
                        <div class='col_full_name'>fullname 2</div>
                        <div class='col_email'>email 2</div>
                    </td>
                    <td> junk 2-2 </td>
                    <td> junk 2-3 </td>
                    <td> junk 2-4 </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class='col_hideable'>
                        <div class='col_nick_name'>nickname 3</div>
                        <div class='col_full_name'>fullname 3</div>
                        <div class='col_email'>email 3</div>
                    </td>
                    <td> junk 3-2 </td>
                    <td> junk 3-3 </td>
                    <td> junk 3-4 </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Added 2011-08-15 13:30**

to implement this in your code, you need to add thous lines inside your head-tag

```
    <script>
        function select_column(column_name)
        {
            document.getElementById('column_style').textContent = '.col_hideable div.col_' + column_name + ' {display: block;}';
        }
    </script>
    <style id='column_style'>
        .col_hideable div.col_nick_name {display: block;}
    </style>
    <style>
        TH, TD {border: solid gray 1px;}
        .col_hideable div {display: none;}
    </style>
```

and replace the table-header code

```
$participants .= "<tr>";
$participants .= "<th>Nickname</th><th>Time (Hours &amp; Mins)</th><th>Average Effort</th><th>Calories</th><th><img src='../images/mepslogo.png' /></th>";
$participants .= "</tr>";
```

with

```
$participants .= "<tr>";
$participants .= "  <th>";
$participants .= "    <select id='column_selector' onchange='select_column(this.value)'>";
$participants .= "      <option value='nick_name'>Nickname</option>";
$participants .= "      <option value='full_name'>Full name</option>";
$participants .= "      <option value='email'>Email</option>";
$participants .= "    </select>";
$participants .= "  </th>";
$participants .= "  <th>Time (Hours &amp; Mins)</th>";
$participants .= "  <th>Average Effort</th>";
$participants .= "  <th>Calories</th>";
$participants .= "  <th><img src='../images/mepslogo.png' /></th>";
$participants .= "</tr>";
```

and replace the table-body code

```
if ($include == 1)
{
    $participants .= "<tr><td>" . $grow['usrNickname'] . "</td><td>" . FormatTime($pDuration) . "</td><td>$pAverageEffort</td><td>" . floor($pCalories) . "</td><td>$pPoints</td></tr>";
}
```

with

```
if ($include == 1)
{
    $participants .= "<tr>";
    $participants .= "  <td class='col_hideable'>";
    $participants .= "    <div class='col_nick_name'>" . $grow['usrNickname'] . "</div>";
    $participants .= "    <div class='col_full_name'>" . $grow['usrFullname'] . "</div>";
    $participants .= "    <div class='col_email'>" . $grow['usrEmail'] . "</div>";
    $participants .= "  </td>";
    $participants .= "  <td>" . FormatTime($pDuration) . "</td>";
    $participants .= "  <td>" . $pAverageEffort . "</td>";
    $participants .= "  <td>" . floor($pCalories) . "</td>";
    $participants .= "  <td>" . $pPoints . "</td>";
    $participants .= "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: but the data coming from database (mysql)...if the user select the full name in the table in combobox that was set in the nick name column the full names will be displayed in place of nick names for the users..the full names and email id are stored in mysql ...database..

Comment: ok, added what parts you could replace to gain the functionanlity from the exemple

Comment: do i need to change this query   $query = "SELECT DISTINCT usrIndex,usrNickname";
$query .= " FROM hrheader hrh";
$query .= " INNER JOIN `user` usr ON hrh.hrhUsrIndex=usr.usrIndex";
$query .= " WHERE usrSIndex=$gIndex";
$query .= " AND hrhStart>'" . $start . "' AND hrhStart<'" . date("Y-m-d", strtotime($end . " +1 days")) . "'";
$query .= " ORDER BY usrNickname";

Comment: because the nick name is coming from user database and query for that is above

Comment: replace "SELECT DISTINCT usrIndex,usrNickname" with "SELECT usr.*", and replace " ORDER BY usrNickname" with " GROUP BY usr.usrIndex ORDER BY usrNickname", mysql recomendations is to use groupby insted of distinct when posible, and as you need all 4 fields in usr, just ask for "usr.*"

Comment: and do i need to change any html code that i have specified in html code for main program().in my question... pls because i am not able to see those details...in table

Comment: <span id="spanParticipants">
<table style='text-align:center;font-size:18px;width:980px;margin-top:16px;color:#231f20;'>
    <tr>
        <th>Nickname</th><th>No of Sessions</th><th>Duration</th><th>Average Effort</th><th><img src='../images/mepslogo.png' /></th>
    </tr>
</table>
    </span>  but i have problem with this code , i am not able to see the table with data do i need to change the data at here

Comment: @user682417 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2492/discussion-between-puggan-se-and-user682417)

Comment: hi puggan pls take a look at this one....http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2524/discussion-between-val-and-user682417